# how to get a word from list on click in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

**I have a list with words. When I'm clicking on button "Next, i  want to display the next word on TextView.**

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    display = findViewById(R.id.dispalay);
    worldList = new ArrayList<>();
    worldList.add("cat");//i want to display this word firstly
    worldList.add("dog");//it after click
    worldList.add("monkey");//after it
    worldList.add("bird");//after it
    worldList.add("fish");//etc
    worldList.add("home");//etc
    worldList.add("car");//etc


public void onClickYes(View view) {
    int i = 0;
    while(i < worldList.size()){
        display.setText(worldList.get(i));
        i++;
        //There is i get an incorrect resolte, because i'm getting last word only.
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

declare `int i=0` as a global variable or outside `onClickYes` method. In `onClickYes` method, use `if` method instead of `while`. You will get next word

```
int i = 0;
public void onClickYes(View view) {
  if(i < worldList.size()) {
    display.setText(worldList.get(i));
    i++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

declare `int i = 0;` outside `onClickYes` method, e.g. line above, and exchange `while` to `if`

```
int i = 0;

public void onClickYes(View view) {
    if(i < worldList.size()){
        display.setText(worldList.get(i));
        i++;
        //There is i get an incorrect resolte, because i'm getting last word only.
    }
}
```

currently every time when button is clicked you are creating new local variable `i=0`, so every `worldList.get(i)` call will return item at position 0 for you. keep `i` outside - it will preserve its value (when you call `i++`) to next button press

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
int i = 0;
public void onClickYes(View view) {
    if(i>=worldList.size()) return;
    display.setText(worldList.get(i));
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could work out.

```
int i = 0;

public void onClickYes(View view) {
   display.setText(worldList.get(i));
   if (i < worldList.size() - 1) {
      i++;
   } else {
      i = 0;
   }
}
```